# How to keep JavaScript from adding my text as numbers

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have text like this: 4.72% - 12.04% that I am putting in a JavaScript object property which I am trying to add to the page kind of like this:

```
$("#container").append("<div>" + rates.fixedrates + "</div>");
```

And JavaScript keeps trying to calculate the numbers even though that's not what I'm trying to do. It doesn't print the text, just NaN.

How can I tell JS to stop this? I've even tried replacing the "-" with `&mdash;` and it does the same thing. Is there something I don't know about that can stop this?

EDIT:

The data comes in from an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Search/Rates",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { oe: ui.item.oe },
    success: function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (rates, index, arr) {
            $("#container").append("<div>" + currentValue.fixedrates + "</div>");
        });
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
return Json(rates);
```

"FixedRates" is just a string property off of the c# object "rates". Nothing special.

Comment: How is `rates.fixedrates` assigned?

Comment: It comes from a text property off of a C# object and is just FixedRates = "4.72% - 12.04%"

Comment: It is in C# then, you probably need to do FixedRates.ToString()

Comment: FixedRates is a string... and JavaScripts toString doens't do anything either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for brevity/clarity I left out a lot of what was in the appended `<div>`. I found out that I had something like this going on:

```
"<div>" + <-- extra plus sign
+ rates.FixedRates + "</div>"
```

So basically it was like this:

```
"<div>" + + rates.FixedRates + "</div>"
```

I guess there is something to be said about posting everything.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine in what I can only assume is the most standard way - You're probably doing something wrong with how the value is assigned, or concatenating

```js
const rates = {
  fixedRates: ''
};

// Joining ourselves
let a = '4.72%';
let b = '12.04%';
let c = a + ' - ' + b;

// Together already
let d =  '4.72% - 12.04%';

rates.fixedRates = c;
$("#container").append("<div>" + rates.fixedRates + "</div>");

rates.fixedRates = d;
$("#container").append("<div>" + rates.fixedRates + "</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I get the string from the database... and it is like this "4.72% - 12.04%", so unless I want to do some chopping and putting back togther... this won't work for me.

Comment: `let a = "4.72% - 12.04%".split(' - ');` - Eitherway, I've updated my answer to show that even joined together this should work

Comment: @BarryFranklin I think you should add the code for retrieving and storing `rates.fixedrates` to the question as it is almost certainly the source of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will take the input and convert it to a text node before inserting it into the div which is then inserted into the container. Let me know how this works out for you..

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Search/Rates",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { oe: ui.item.oe },
    success: function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (rates, index, arr) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            var textContent = document.createTextNode(currentValue.fixedrates);
            var container = document.getElementById('container');

            div.appendChild(textContent);
            container.appendChild('div'); 
        });
    }
});
```